# Responsive Bootstrap Sticky Footer Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sticky-footer

When the window is resized, the height of the footer expands but not the background color. Help!

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html
[image: Sticky Footer Bootstrap]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`height: auto` seems to solve the problem. You can include it with a media query for small viewports:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #footer {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with the latest version of Bootstrap?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the original issue with the latest version of Bootstrap, could you please report what OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Windows 8, Chrome 37.0.2062.120 m

Comment: Probably because the viewport max width is emulated.

Answer (score 3):

Your demo doesn't work anymore but the best Bootstrap sticky footer I've found is: https://gist.github.com/aalaap/3066704

Comment: The example is still online but the URL changed: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Comment: @clarif As mentioned below - the bootstrap example uses a fixed height and is not responsive.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh Yes, it does. You're welcome to post a link to a fiddle with an example where you can't get it to work and I'm sure someone will be able to help you get it working.